# How to get enum value by keyname

Tags: c#

```
public enum aa{ a1=1,a2=2,a3=6,...,a100=203}
```

How to get value like this

```
string att=GetFromDatabase("attribute");    //this return a1 or a2 ...
Enum.GetValue(att);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Solution

```
string name = GetFromDatabase("attribute");
Enum.Parse(typeof(aa),name);
```

Comment: This will return an object, you will need to cast it to get an enum

Answer (score 10):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
aa attEnum = (aa)Enum.Parse(typeof(aa), att);
```

Go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)

```
string att=GetFromDatabase("attribute");    //this return a1 or a2 ...
Enum.Parse(typeof(aa), att);
```