# How to fetch value of enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have defined an enum like

```
public Enum CompanyQuarters
{
     First=1,
     Second=2,
     Third=3,
     Fourth=4
}
```

I bind them to dropdown list like

```
ddlCompQuarter.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(CompanyQuarters));
ddlCompQuarter.DataBind();
```

Now I want to fetch the dropdownlist selected value For e.g for selection 'second' I like to fetch 2 ?

This does not work

```
 int selectedVal = int.Parse(ddlCompQuarter.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: BTW, What is `CompanyQuarters`? (you've provided just ActiveQuarters )

Comment: My bad, just a typo (corrected post)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get enum value by keyname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540746/how-to-get-enum-value-by-keyname)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ActiveQuarters value = (ActiveQuarters)Enum.Parse(typeof(ActiveQuarters),ddlCompQuarter.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

or if you are using Dot Net Framework 4 or greater, see [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx)

```
ActiveQuarters value;
Enum.TryParse<ActiveQuarters>(ddlCompQuarter.SelectedValue.ToString(), out value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here I am showing you the best way to use enum:

```
public enum enumVIPBusinessPlanPaymentType {
    [Description("Monthly")]
    Monthly = 1,
    [Description("Paid In Full (PIF)")]
    PaidInFull = 2,
    [Description("Barter")]
    Barter = 3 }
```

and create a `EnumHelper.cs` class to read its value or description

```
public static Int32 GetIntValue(Enum en)
    {
        Type type = en.GetType();
        return TemplateControlExtension.GetInt32(null, en);
    }

public static string GetStringNameFromValue(Enum en)
    {
        Type type = en.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] info = type.GetMember(en.ToString());
        if (info != null && info.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = info[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            {
               return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
            }
        }
        return TemplateControlExtension.GetString(null, en);
    }
```

I hope it will like you

Comment: Nice, I like your approach, very clean.

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveQuarters typedValue = (ActiveQuarters)Enum.Parse(typeof(ActiveQuarters), 
                                              ddlCompQuarter.SelectedValue);

// If you need numeric value
int numericValue = (int)typedValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CompanyQuarters comp= (CompanyQuarters)Enum.Parse(ddlCompQuarter.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)

```
var val = (int)(ActiveQuarters)Enum.Parse(typeof(ActiveQuarters), 
                                          ddlCompQuarter.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Also I think your code has problem, you defined `ActiveQuarters` enum and you bind `CompanyQuarters`!.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reverse the way you got the names in there.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2004/04/02/106310.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Enum.Parse and then you can get your enum from ComboBox

Answer (score 1):

You have to set text and value property at time of binding the drop down.
For value field you can use

**Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumProvider.CompanyQuarters))**